# SpringBoot application can't resolve thymeleaf view

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm running the code in ch21 of "spring in action 4th" in IDEA, a simple springboot web application. But it does'nt work, which does'nt resolve thymeleaf veiw.

I have modified the view name to html filename, it works. But the model can't be displayed.

Controller

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ContactController {

    private ContactRepository contactRepo;

    @Autowired
    public ContactController(ContactRepository contactRepo) {
        this.contactRepo = contactRepo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Map<String,Object> model) {
        List<Contact> contacts = contactRepo.findAll();
        model.put("contacts", contacts);
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submit(Contact contact) {
        contactRepo.save(contact);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

maven pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.github.lxyscls.SpringInAction4th</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringInAction4th-ch21</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I put the html under src/main/resources/templates.

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <title>Spring Boot Contacts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/style.css}" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Spring Boot Contacts</h2>
    <form method="POST">
      <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstName"></input><br/>
      <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastName"></input><br/>
      <label for="phoneNumber">Phone #:</label>
      <input type="text" name="phoneNumber"></input><br/>
      <label for="emailAddress">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="emailAddress"></input><br/>
      <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>

    <ul th:each="contact : ${contacts}">
      <li>
        <span th:text="${contact.firstName}">First</span>
        <span th:text="${contact.lastName}">Last</span> :
        <span th:text="${contact.phoneNumber}">phoneNumber</span>,
        <span th:text="${contact.emailAddress}">emailAddress</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error logs are as below.

```
17:03:23.339 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView - View name 'home', model {contacts=[]}
17:03:23.340 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView - Forwarding to [home]
17:03:23.342 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/home", parameters={}
17:03:23.345 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
17:03:23.346 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Resource not found
17:03:23.346 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
17:03:23.347 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: That's not where you're supposed to put the template. public is for static assets, not for templates. Read the guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, according to the book, I have put the home.html under resources/templates, does not work yet.

Comment: "does not work" is much too vague. Tell precisely what you're doing, what you expect to happen and what happens instead, including, if any, the complete and exact error you get.

Comment: I want to get the homepage at localhost:8080, not 404(Whitelabel Error Page). And I have given more debug logs from IDEA. Thanks for you patient.

Comment: what is your html file name ?

Comment: @Sachin home.html

Comment: What is the url you are trying to call ? is it http://localhost:8080/home ?

Comment: a minor suggestion which I believe will make your code nicer: instead of `@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)` you can use `@GetMapping` and instead of `@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)` you can use `@PostMapping`.

Comment: @Sachin no, localhost:8080. I think the home method will give it a view named in "home".

Answer (score 1):

The error log shows you are trying to do a GET request to `/home` but i don't see any request mapping to `/home` in your controller class. You have defined class level RequestMapping to `/`. You could try calling http://localhost:8080 which should take you to the home.html page or you could define RequestMapping to your home method somethying like below and try calling http://localhost:8080/home

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Map<String,Object> model) {..}
```

Comment: I think it can't add the "value = /home" to the home method. Because the method return the "home" view name, it is Circular . Error as below. Circular view path [home]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/home] again. Check your ViewResolver setup!

Comment: can you share your xml/java configuration ?

Comment: I have putted maven pom and java controller code and some error logs in the question.